# Effective way to remove everything after last ? from string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to strip everything that follows and includes the last  `?` of a given url. I am currently working with `preg_replace` but no luck in accomplishing the goal. This is the regex `#\/[^?]*$#` I am using to single out the last `?`. Also is there a faster way by using `substr`?

Example link:

```
preg_replace('#\/[^?]*$#', '', $post="www.exapmle.com?26sf213132aasdf1312sdf31")
```

Desired Output

```
www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `\?` at start of regex instead of `\/`

```
\?[^?]*$
```

- `\?`  matches a `?`
- `[^?]*$` matches anything other than a `?` until the end of string anchored by `$`

Example  http://regex101.com/r/sW6jE7/3

```
$post="www.exapmle.com?26sf213132aasdf1312sdf31";
$res=preg_replace('/\?[^?]*$/', '', $post);
echo $res;
```

will give an output

```
www.example.com
```

**EDIT**

If you want to remove the entire query string from url then a slight modifiation of regex would do the work

`\?.*$`

which will remove anything followed by a question mark

Comment: If this is going to be from user provided data, something like `www.example.com?foo#bar?` will break it.

Comment: *I am trying to strip everything that follows and includes the last  ? of a given url*. So here it would remove the `?` after the `bar`.

Comment: Sure, if that's what you want. By saying '?' in a url context I took that as you want to remove the query string in which anything after the # is not a part of.

Comment: @tigrang Yeah i got you. But i wrote it going with the OPs example. Hoping that it would be something he wants

Comment: @tigrang I have added that part to my answer. Hope its fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with `substr` and `strrpos`:

```
$post = "www.exapmle.com?26sf213132aasdf1312sdf31";
$pos = strrpos($post, '?');
$result = substr($post, 0, $pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply match everything from the start upto the `?` symbol.

```
preg_match('/^[^?\n]*/', $post="www.exapmle.com?26sf213132aasdf1312sdf31", $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Output:

```
www.exapmle.com
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this its working fine :**

```
$host_url = "www.exapmle.com?26sf213132aasdf1312sdf31";
$part_url = strrpos($host_url, '?');
$result = substr($host_url, 0, $part_url);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although OP tags regex, Surprisingly nobody suggests `explode()`, which is much easier.

```
$post = "www.exapmle.com?26sf213132aasdf1312sdf31";
$tokens = explode('?', $post);
echo $tokens[0]; // www.exapmle.com
```